# Displaying text next to a drop down box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdownbox

I'm looking to display a sales price in text next to a drop down box, but there's a catch.

Here is my current code:

```
<SELECT name="SELECT___TK46BW___9" onChange="change_option('SELECT___TK46BW___9',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<OPTION value="124" SELECTED>1 Box</OPTION>
<OPTION value="125" >2 per Case [Add $10.95]</OPTION>
<OPTION value="126" >6 per Case [Add $50.00]</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Now, the rub is I can't change that part of the code. I can put HTML and Javascript underneath it, but the above is automatically generated by the platform that I'm using.

I hope I was specific enough in this post. Thank you for any help!

EDIT

If possible, I'm looking for it to look something like this:
[image]

Comment: atleast you have control after this part of HTML is generated right?

Comment: Yes, I just can't change the code that I posted above.

Comment: No problem, but you can append a 'text' or a `span` next to dropdown right?

Comment: As long as it is after the </SELECT>

Comment: And where do the `22.95` come from  on your image? Cause 2 x 10.95 = `21.9`

Comment: It should be 12.95, 22.95, 62.95

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my attempt at solving this, in this example on clicking the button we update the option with the value "126".

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/xor4f0rs/

HTML:

```
<SELECT name="SELECT___TK46BW___9" onChange="change_option('SELECT___TK46BW___9',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
  <OPTION value="124" SELECTED>1 Box</OPTION>
  <OPTION value="125" >2 per Case [Add $10.95]</OPTION>
  <OPTION value="126" >6 per Case [Add $50.00]</OPTION>
</SELECT>

<button id="btn">click me</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $("option[value='126']").html('6 per Case [Add $99.99]')
});
```

Edit: SOLUTION https://jsfiddle.net/xor4f0rs/9/

Comment: Thanks, Brad. Unfortunately, it's not working in a couple of my browsers.

Comment: you are using jquery in your project?

Comment: Yes, but when I click the button, it reloads the page and changes to the first option value.

Comment: @DanD is this what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/xor4f0rs/3/ ?

Comment: Brad, is there a way where it can be down without the button and popup?

Comment: @DanD which bit? changing the price in the option text? if so, where is the new price coming from?

Comment: That's kind of the problem. I am assuming it can't be changed dynamically because I can't change that code, so I would have to input it myself someway. Something like this: var DivTxt = new Array()
DivTxt[124] = "12.95"
DivTxt[125] = "22.95"
DivTxt[126] = "62.95"

Comment: If this is helpful, and again sorry for the confusion, this is the pricing structure:

1 Box: 12.95
2 per Case: 22.95
6 per Case: 62.95

Comment: @DanD so the prices you are changing it to, they don't change? so then something like this will do: https://jsfiddle.net/xor4f0rs/7/

Comment: @Brad Yes! That is fantastic! Is there anyway to get rid of the button, or will that need to be there?

Comment: @DanD so just saw the pic in your update, so you dont want to change the values in the dropdown, just the value that is displayed in the text bit after? is there any relationship bewteen the original price and new price? e.g its plus 50% or something?

Comment: @DanD just removed the button from HTML https://jsfiddle.net/xor4f0rs/8/

Comment: @DanD if this solved it would you mind marking this as the answer? thanks

Comment: @Brad Thank you again, I marked it as the answer. I appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: @Brad, one last thing if it's not too much of a pain. Is there any way to hide the [Add $62.95] in the dropdown box and have it just show on the script you made? For example, the dropdown would say "6 per Case" and the script would say "The price is $62.95." Thanks!

Comment: @DanD i have to run out, ill look at it tonight and get back to you

Comment: @DanD ok mate, this i think is what you want. I have created 2 functions to avoid too much repetition.  I have commented as best i can but if anything is unclear let me know. https://jsfiddle.net/xor4f0rs/9/

Comment: @Brad Thank you, Brad. You are the MAN!

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```js
$('select').on('change', function(){
    $('.show-price').text($(this).find("option:selected").text());
});
```

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px orange;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<SELECT name="SELECT___TK46BW___9" onChange="change_option('SELECT___TK46BW___9',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<OPTION value="124" SELECTED>1 Box</OPTION>
<OPTION value="125" >2 per Case [Add $10.95]</OPTION>
<OPTION value="126" >6 per Case [Add $50.00]</OPTION>
</SELECT>

<div class="show-price">
No price selected
</div>

<script>
function change_option(){  }; // just make sure the function exists for no errors
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it's getting there. What I need to do though is show a different price other than the dropdown. For example, if the dropdown is 6 per Case [Add $50] - it would show $72.95.

Comment: @DanD that's a new question don't you think? Your title says `Displaying text next to a drop down box` not calculating prices based on string from option on change .. :)

Comment: Sorry, caramba. I would manually put the text in for the price change.

Comment: @DanD manually based on what? if the string changes the values should also change no?

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't clearer before. I've been getting frustrated not being able to change that code. For example, if I need to (and probably do), when the dropdown is selected, the text next to it would be different than the text in the dropdown itself. If someone selected the first value (1 Box), it would output 12.95.

Comment: I made an edit with a link to a mock image. http://www.itagshippers.com/TK46BW.jpg

Comment: 12.95 is the price for the first option, 1 Box.